# How to pass an argument through a function which call other functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

The simpler version of my problem looks like the following:

```
def function_1(x, function):
    print(x)
    function()


def function_2(y):
    print(2*y)


def function_3(z, n):
    print(3*z)
    print(5 * n)


function_1(5, function_2)
function_1(3, function_3)
```

My question is when calling function_1, how can i give it an argument which will be added to the called function (function_2 or function_3) also as an argument?
Beginner here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "python args", or check this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/, this will allow you to `function_1(5, function_3, 4, 5)` and to `function_1(3, function_2, 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
...
function_1(5, partial(function_2, 5))
function_1(3, partial(function_3, 2, 3))
```

`partial` lets you pass a object to `function_1` that can be called with no passed parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As Kacper suggested, Python offers the possibility of using arbitrary positional arguments lists (args) and keyword arguments dicts (kwargs):

```
def fun_x(x, a_callable, *args, **kwargs):
    print(x, a_callable, args, kwargs)
    a_callable(*args, **kwargs)

def fun_y(a,b,kwarg1):
    print(a,b,kwarg1)

fun_x(3,fun_y, "first", "second", kwarg1="third")

3 <function fun_y at 0x000001D1E0E02378> ('first', 'second') {'kwarg1': 'third'}
first second third
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by adding `x` to the parameters?

```
def function_1(x, function):
    print(x)
    function(x)
...
```

Comment: Not really, i updated the post, i'd like to use different arguments for x and for the called functions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same argument **x** to **function_1** as an argument to called function inside then you can use:

`def function_1(x, function):
    print(x)
    function(x)`

or you want to use another argument **y** for function which is called inside then you can use like below:

`def function_1(x,y,function):
    print(x)
    function(y)`

Comment: And what if i want to use different number of arguments for function_2 and function_3, like in the updated post?